# Hide child <div>s as parent div shrinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to write a zoom in/out feature on a web app I am making using the jqueryUI slider.

I am having difficulty handling when my parent div shrinks too much, and cramps its child containers.

```
   <div class="puck originator inline-block" style="width: 310.5px; left: 0px;">
    <div class="conflicted inline-block originator">
        <div class="right-number">I should stay</div>
        <div class="left-number">I should stay</div>
        <div class="middle-number">I Should disapper</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant section of code I have
http://jsfiddle.net/aQKwE/

Basically I have the parent div (class 'puck') that is being shrunk using a jquery slider. For this code I just used a text box, but same idea.

When I shrink that div, the containing divs stick around and are very garbled.

I want to be able to remove the middle child div when it becomes to cramped, leaving the left and right child divs to occupy all the space

Furthermore, if it becomes to cramped yet after that, I want to remove the right div, leaving only the left.

Finally I want to be able to remove all contents so that nothing more than the background of the parent shows.

Is there a way to do this easily, preferably through CSS? I don't want to write more javascript code to set 'display:none' on each child div, since it seems like some CSS rules should handle this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you shrink/expand the font-size? as you zoom/in out?

Comment: css `overflow: hidden;` should do the trick, if you dont want to hide elements one by one and no javascript.

Comment: Here's an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCz8h/2/) using logic similar to @MochDaear's, but using the `resize()` event as the trigger.

Comment: my issue with this solution, however, is I have close to 100-200 of these 'pucks' on the app, and all are resized, so I am worried that performing this logic on that many will be a performance hit, particlarly sincee ie has such a crappy javascript engine.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really any logic built into CSS to handle something like this. You can set rules based on viewport size, but that won't help in this case.

I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQKwE/5/) with this code so you can test it and see what you think, but essentially I just added some checks in your javascript function to hide based on the width submitted.

```
    var newwidth = $('#text').val();
    $(".middle-number").show();   
    $(".right-number").show();  
    if (newwidth < 280) {
         $(".middle-number").hide();   
    }
    if (newwidth < 180) {
         $(".right-number").hide();   
    }
    $('.puck').css('width',newwidth);
```